# How to install tensorflow in raspberry pi with python 3.5.3

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, raspberry-pi

**Summery**

When I use `Sudo pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow`, I get

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

When I use `pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow`, I get

> MemoryError

When I use  `sudo pip3 install tensorflow --no-cache-dir`, it is installing but cannot use in python.

When I use `pip3 install tensorflow --no-cache-dir`, I get

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'

---

I am using Raspbian Stretch with desktop and recommended software new version which is released in 2018-11-13. I am using raspberry pi 2 modal B.

I tried to install tensorflow according to recommended google guide. [LINK](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip)

Result of envirement.
[image: result]

When I give command `pip3 install --user --upgrade tensorflow` I got this error at 99 completeded of download.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 353, in run
    wb.build(autobuilding=True)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/wheel.py", line 749, in build
    self.requirement_set.prepare_files(self.finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 620, in _prepare_file
    session=self.session, hashes=hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 821, in unpack_url
    hashes=hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 659, in unpack_http_url
    hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 882, in _download_http_url
    _download_url(resp, link, content_file, hashes)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 603, in _download_url
    hashes.check_against_chunks(downloaded_chunks)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/hashes.py", line 46, in check_against_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 571, in written_chunks
    for chunk in chunks:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/utils/ui.py", line 139, in iter
    for x in it:
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 560, in resp_read
    decode_content=False):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 432, in stream
    data = self.read(amt=amt, decode_content=decode_content)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/response.py", line 380, in read
    data = self._fp.read(amt)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 63, in read
    self._close()
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/filewrapper.py", line 50, in _close
    self.__callback(self.__buf.getvalue())
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/controller.py", line 275, in cache_response
    self.serializer.dumps(request, response, body=body),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 55, in dumps
    "body": _b64_encode_bytes(body),
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/CacheControl-0.11.7-py2.py3-none-any.whl/cachecontrol/serialize.py", line 12, in _b64_encode_bytes
    return base64.b64encode(b).decode("ascii")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/base64.py", line 59, in b64encode
    encoded = binascii.b2a_base64(s)[:-1]
MemoryError
```

After that, I tried `pip3 install --no-cache-dir tensorflow` code but I got following error after finish the download.

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 594, in urlopen
    chunked=chunked)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 391, in _make_request
    six.raise_from(e, None)
  File "<string>", line 2, in raise_from
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 387, in _make_request
    httplib_response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 1198, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 297, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/http/client.py", line 258, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/socket.py", line 576, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 937, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 799, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/ssl.py", line 583, in read
    v = self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ConnectionResetError: [Errno 104] Connection reset by peer

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    requirement_set.prepare_files(finder)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 380, in prepare_files
    ignore_dependencies=self.ignore_dependencies))
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 554, in _prepare_file
    require_hashes
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 278, in populate_link
    self.link = finder.find_requirement(self, upgrade)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 465, in find_requirement
    all_candidates = self.find_all_candidates(req.name)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 423, in find_all_candidates
    for page in self._get_pages(url_locations, project_name):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 568, in _get_pages
    page = self._get_page(location)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 683, in _get_page
    return HTMLPage.get_page(link, session=self.session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/index.py", line 792, in get_page
    "Cache-Control": "max-age=600",
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 501, in get
    return self.request('GET', url, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/pip/download.py", line 386, in request
    return super(PipSession, self).request(method, url, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 488, in request
    resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in send
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 630, in <listcomp>
    history = [resp for resp in gen] if allow_redirects else []
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 190, in resolve_redirects
    **adapter_kwargs
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/sessions.py", line 609, in send
    r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/requests-2.12.4-py2.py3-none-any.whl/requests/adapters.py", line 423, in send
    timeout=timeout
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 643, in urlopen
    _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
  File "/usr/share/python-wheels/urllib3-1.19.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 315, in increment
    total -= 1
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -=: 'Retry' and 'int'
```

How to solve this error?

Update:

When I run `sudo pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade --no-cache-dir`, it say following detail but I can not import tensor library to my project.

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ sudo pip3 install tensorflow --upgrade --no-cache-dir
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorflow in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages
Requirement already up-to-date: tensorboard<1.12.0,>=1.11.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: astor>=0.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: setuptools<=39.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: numpy>=1.13.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: keras-preprocessing>=1.0.3 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: wheel>=0.26 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: protobuf>=3.6.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: keras-applications>=1.0.5 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: grpcio>=1.8.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: absl-py>=0.1.6 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: termcolor>=1.1.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: gast>=0.2.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: six>=1.10.0 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: markdown>=2.6.8 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.12.0,>=1.11.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: werkzeug>=0.11.10 in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from tensorboard<1.12.0,>=1.11.0->tensorflow)
Requirement already up-to-date: h5py in /usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages (from keras-applications>=1.0.5->tensorflow)
```

When I import the tensorflow I get following error massage.

```
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: compiletime version 3.4 of module 'tensorflow.python.framework.fast_tensor_util' does not match runtime version 3.5
  return f(*args, **kwds)
/usr/lib/python3.5/importlib/_bootstrap.py:222: RuntimeWarning: builtins.type size changed, may indicate binary incompatibility. Expected 432, got 412
  return f(*args, **kwds)
```

Answer (score 2):

It seems that it is caused by some packages' version conflict problems. The virtual environment solution at [Install TensorFlow with pip  |  TensorFlow](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) worked for me

Comment: I was getting exactly the same error installing tensor flow with python3.5. Installing into a virtual environment as per the link worked. So it must have been a conflict with some other packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since tensorflow 1.9 supports raspberry pi, if you follow this [link](https://medium.com/tensorflow/tensorflow-1-9-officially-supports-the-raspberry-pi-b91669b0aa0), this much is what is required to do.

```
sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev
pip3 install tensorflow
```

you can check the installation by running this code.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.enable_eager_execution()
hello = tf.constant(‘Hello, TensorFlow!’)
print(hello)
```

Comment: I already this sudo apt install libatlas-base-dev code and it is up to date. when i run the pip3 install tensorflow it give me above error

Comment: please check if you have urllib3 installed? if not install it and try it again

Comment: When I use sudo pip3 install tensorflow it is installing but can not add that library. when i use pip3 install tensorflow can not install get above error

Comment: these are not errors but runtime warning, please check with the code in the updated answer, runtime warning arises due python 3.4 a and 3.5, dont worry about these warning your tensorflow is now working which means urllib3 was the issue. please upvote my answer if my suggestion helped you!

Comment: I got this tf.Tensor(b'HelloTensorFlow', shape=(), dtype=string). Is it fine?

Comment: before installing urllib3 I got same warning massage

Comment: Thats fine if you think so, but when you are posting questions on public forums, atleast try to maintain integrity of forums, especially stackoverflow, Thanks

Comment: None of suggestions worked for me. Only the virtual environment approach worked.